# Merge two images in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am showing users on a map view with custom markers. Each marker will contain the user's image, like in the image below:[image]

There might be multiple users displayed as markers on the map. I get the data of users and their images through an API. The image which I receive from the API is just a rectangular image. But I have to show that image very similar to the above shown image. So I thought of two solution.

1. Get the marker image from the API itself that can be easily displayed as an image on the map.
2. I have the outer ellipse as an image. I can place a round image in that ellipse and create a new image. That can further be used as a marker. But for this I'll have to merge two photos. I am able to merge them. But the users image is always rectangle. I am not able to make it round.

Can any one help me with a better solution or just complete my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option will be the easiest. If you re going with the second option then here's something:

```
-(UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(UIImage *) image 
                  radius: (float) radius {

  CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
  imageLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
  imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
  imageLayer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;
  imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
  imageLayer.cornerRadius = radius;
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
  [imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return roundedImage;
}
```

This will create a round UIImage with a white background. Just use the resulting UIImage as the marker icon.

Comment: Perfect!! :) This was what I was looking for. I converted your code to swift. And works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

This won't answer you question completely, but to rounder the imageView use this(This code is in objective C and the "profilePic" is an example UIImageView):

```
    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.size.width / 2;
```

Comment: This is not an answer. I have not asked to make the UIImageView round. My question was to make UIImage round.